# Плавный аккордеон js

Tags: javascript

Как сделать плавный раскрывающийся аккордеон. Подразумеваю что регулируется установкой высоты блока и св-ом трансишн. Не давайте рыбу, напиши словами чтобы сам сделал.

```js
var btn_title = document.querySelectorAll('.test_title');
var disc = document.querySelectorAll('.test_disc');

for (var i = 0; i < btn_title.length; i++) {
  btn_title[i].addEventListener('click', fun_open);

  function fun_open(event) {
    for (var i = 0; i < btn_title.length; i++) {
      disc[i].classList.remove('test_disc_show');
      if (btn_title[i] == event.currentTarget) {
        disc[i].classList.toggle('test_disc_show');
      }
    }

  }

}
```

```css
html .test {
  height: 1000px;
}

html .test_title {
  width: 180px;
  height: 30px;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

html .test_disc {
  width: 180px;
  height: 80px;
  background: blue;
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

html .test_disc_show {
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.9s;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div class="test_title test_title_one">test_title test_title_one</div>
  <!-- /.test_title -->
  <div class="test_disc test_disc_one">test_disc test_disc_one</div>
  <!-- /.test_disc -->
  <div class="test_title test_title_two">test_title test_title_two</div>
  <!-- /.test_title -->
  <div class="test_disc test_disc_two">test_disc test_disc_two</div>
  <!-- /.test_disc -->
  <div class="test_title test_title_one">test_title test_title_one</div>
  <!-- /.test_title -->
  <div class="test_disc test_disc_one">test_disc test_disc_one</div>
  <!-- /.test_disc -->
  <div class="test_title test_title_two">test_title test_title_two</div>
  <!-- /.test_title -->
  <div class="test_disc test_disc_two">test_disc test_disc_two</div>
  <!-- /.test_disc -->
</div>
<!-- /.test -->
```

Comment: `display: none;`   `transition-ну` не поддается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var btn_title = document.querySelectorAll('.test_title');
var disc = document.querySelectorAll('.test_disc');

for (var i = 0; i < btn_title.length; i++) {
  btn_title[i].addEventListener('click', fun_open);

  function fun_open(event) {
    for (var i = 0; i < btn_title.length; i++) {
      disc[i].classList.remove('test_disc_show');
      if (btn_title[i] == event.currentTarget) {
        disc[i].classList.toggle('test_disc_show');
      }
    }

  }

}
```

```css
html .test {
  height: 1000px;
}

html .test_title {
  width: 180px;
  height: 30px;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

html .test_disc {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 180px;
  height: 0;
  background: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transition: all 0.9s;
}

html .test_disc_show {
  height: 80px;
  transition: all 0.9s;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div class="test_title test_title_one">test_title test_title_one</div>
  <!-- /.test_title -->
  <div class="test_disc test_disc_one">test_disc test_disc_one</div>
  <!-- /.test_disc -->
  <div class="test_title test_title_two">test_title test_title_two</div>
  <!-- /.test_title -->
  <div class="test_disc test_disc_two">test_disc test_disc_two</div>
  <!-- /.test_disc -->
  <div class="test_title test_title_one">test_title test_title_one</div>
  <!-- /.test_title -->
  <div class="test_disc test_disc_one">test_disc test_disc_one</div>
  <!-- /.test_disc -->
  <div class="test_title test_title_two">test_title test_title_two</div>
  <!-- /.test_title -->
  <div class="test_disc test_disc_two">test_disc test_disc_two</div>
  <!-- /.test_disc -->
</div>
<!-- /.test -->
```

Answer (score 0):

если вы уверены что текста будут не большого размера, то

```
.test_disc {
  max-height: 0;
  transition: all 0.9s;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.test_disc.test_disc_show {
  max-height: приблизительное_значение_с_запасом px;
}
```

ну или вообще расставлять высоту js... Других вариантов при таком подходе не вижу