# Как сделать такое же меню

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, css-grid

Здравствуйте люди добрые, как сделать точно такое же меню? И чтобы остальные элементы меню также смещались вниз при открытии

[image: гифка с демонстрацией желаемого результата]

Comment: берете, и делаете все меню полностью. Потом подменю скрываете классами. При нажатии меняете класс (например с `d-none` на `d-flex`) И делаете анимашки на них. Вам понадобится: свойстово css `display` для скрытия/разворачивания меню; js `event` `onclick` для замены класса по нажатию "плюсика". И свойство css `animation` и/или `transition` для анимации. На счет смещения элементов - это в `animation` надо поиграться с `%` + `position:absolute (top)`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Плавный аккордеон js](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/787856/%d0%9f%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%bd-js), ответов на этот вопрос миллион, стоило сначала поискать