# Раскрыть конкретный спойлер

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть спойлер который по нажатию на один заголовок (дату) раскрывает все что есть.
**Как сделать, чтобы по нажатию на дату будет раскрываться конкретный спойлер, но не все**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

jquery

```
$('.spoiler-body').hide(300);
    $(document).on('click','.spoiler-head',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        $(this).parents('.spoiler-wrap').toggleClass("active").find('.spoiler-body').toggle();
    })
```

css

```
.spoiler-wrap.disabled .spoiler-body{display:none}
```

html спойлера

```
 <div class="spoiler-wrap">
            <?php
            $current_id = '';
foreach($get_all_conf as  $item) {

    if ($item['date_conf'] !== $current_id) { ?>
        <div class="spoiler-head">
        <?php
        echo '<h2>' . $item['date_conf'] . '</h2>';
        $current_id = $item['date_conf'];
        ?>
        </div>
            <?php
    }
      ?>
    <div class="spoiler-body">
    <?php
    echo  $item['user_reserved'];
    ?>
   </div>
    <?php
}
?>
   </div>
```

Comment: так у вас же было `$(this).next().toggle();` вот он и должен работать как надо.

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, как раз как надо он не работает, выводится ровно одна запись на одну дату

Comment: Поясните яснее что должно быть. Из вопроса не ясно какое итоговое поведение должно быть. Приведите больше html разметки и поясните что в ней должно быть при кликах куда либо

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, по нажатию на дату должен конкретный спойлер раскрываться а не все. Обновил HTML

Comment: Нет, вы не обновили html. Вы показали код с PHP, а нужно чистый сгенерированный html.........Может быть что-то я не понимаю, но кажется вы сами себе противоречите.  "по нажатию на дату должен конкретный спойлер раскрываться а не все"  и  "как раз как надо он не работает, выводится ровно одна запись на одну дату".  - разве это не то что нужно? открывать одну а не все? %)))

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, $(this).next().toggle(); раскрывает один спойлер, в нем ОДНА запись (один раз admin выводится), на картинке ДВЕ (два раза admin выводится), используя вариант описанный в посте раскрываются все спойлеры, оба варианта работают не корректно

Comment: [Вопрос, с ответами, схожими по теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/787856/%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BD-js)

Answer (score 1):

В виду того, что автор не приложил ни конечную HTML-разметку ни стили, предполагаю такое решение:

```js
$(".spoiler-body").hide(300);
$(document).on("click", ".spoiler-head", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this)
    .parents(".spoiler-wrap")
    .toggleClass("active")
    .find(".spoiler-body")
    .toggle(300);
});
```

```css
.spoiler-wrap {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #57aa43;
  font: normal 14px sans-serif;
}

.spoiler-head h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: .3em;
  font: normal 28px sans-serif;
  background-color: #57aa43;
  color: #fff;
}

.spoiler-body {
  display: none;
  padding: .6em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="spoiler-wrap">
  <div class="spoiler-head">
    <h2>21.03.2021</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="spoiler-body">
    admin
  </div>
</div>
<div class="spoiler-wrap">
  <div class="spoiler-head">
    <h2>24.03.2021</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="spoiler-body">
    admin
  </div>
  <div class="spoiler-body">
    admin
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: там и была полная версия HTML (https://skeitol.ru/articles/krasivyj_spojler_na_jquery/) адрес скрипта

Comment: @Юрий: и откуда же нам было знать где она была?

Comment: суть в том, что я полный скрипт выложил, единственное отличие, это вывод из php